# Why is `initialize_block` in the `Core` runtime API (as opposed to `BlockBuilder`)?

Tags: runtime-api

Every Substrate runtime implements several Runtime APIs. Two essential ones are the `Core` and `BlockBuilder` APIs.

The [`Core` API](https://crates.parity.io/sp_api/trait.Core.html) is for executing blocks, a task that will be performed by all nodes. A simplification of its definition is as follows:

```
pub trait Core {
  fn initialize_block(header: &Header);

  fn execute_block(block: Block);

  // Less relevant functions elided
}
```

The [`BlockBuilder` API](https://crates.parity.io/sp_block_builder/trait.BlockBuilder.html) is for constructing blocks, a task that only a validator or miner would perform. To summarize its definition:

```
pub trait BlockBuilder: Core {
  fn apply_extrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic) -> ApplyExtrinsicResult;

  fn finalize_block() -> Header;

  // Less relevant functions elided
}
```

It seems to me that building a block should involve initializing, applying several extrinsics, and then finalizing. It also seems natural that executing an already built block should be a single task with any initialization being part of the execution.

This is the approach taken by the [rust-blockchain project](https://github.com/rust-blockchain/blockchain/blob/master/core/src/traits.rs#L66-L117)

Cumulus also seems to take this approach for validating parachain blocks with its single [`validate_block` function](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/8befd605b6a29210cb47c74ed484e90f90ebaaac/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs#L43).

Finally, even Substrate hints at this design with its requirement `trait BlockBuilder: Core`

So why does Substrate include `initialize_block` along with the Core API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are historical reasons. As I implemented the runtime api in the current form as traits, we always called `initialize_block` before every runtime api function call. Thus, I moved the call to the `Core` api. We removed this requirement on calling `initialize_block` for every runtime api function call and now it would make more sense to move it to the `BlockBuilder` api.